# Arduino Uno Timing Issues

Tags: bluetooth, arduino-uno, benchmarking

I have been trying to make a robotic "gutter cleaner" for a school project. I decided to use an Arduino Uno to control the motors. It's only a forward/reverse drive and therefore only has one motor controlling the motion of the robot. There is another motor controlling the "blades" (for lack of a better word) coming out the front to fling the dirt out of the gutter.

I am using a HC-05 Bluetooth module to accept input from a smartphone and a L9110 H-bridge to control the motors separately. There are five functions: forward motion, reverse motion, blades on, stop and "autonomous". Autonomous involves the blades being on with the robot moving forward for 20 seconds, backwards for 10 seconds, repeating until the stop function is called.

The problem is that when I call the function for the autonomous, the HC-06 seems to stop receiving data and the debug `println("auto fwd")` spams the Serial Monitor. The "auto rev" code debug code isn't even reached. The stop function cannot run as it appears no data is being received so an infinite loop is created.

I've tried using BlinkWithoutDelay here and I honestly have no idea why this isn't working.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> //Include the "SoftwareSerial" software in the program

#define M1A 5 //tells the software compiler to assign these varibales to these outputs on the Arduino board
#define M1B 9 //M1 motors are controlling the motion
#define M2A 4 //M2 motors control the blades
#define M2B 10

SoftwareSerial BT(3, 2); //Tells the program to assign pins 2 and 3 on the Arduino to send and receive data

void fw(); //Denoting Functions to be used
void bw();
void Stop();
void autonomous();
void bladesOn();

boolean autonom = false; //Variables
boolean blades = false;
unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
const long fwdTime = 20000;
const long revTime = fwdTime/2;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  TCCR1B = (TCCR1B & 0b11111000) | 0x04;
  BT.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(M1A, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(M1B, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(M2A, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(M2B, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if (BT.available()) {
    char input = BT.read(); //Read the incoming BlueTooth signal
    Serial.println(input); //Print the BT signal to the memory
    switch (input) { //IF input is 1, do this, IF input is 2, do that
      case '1':
        fw();
        break;
      case '2':
        bw();
        break;
      case '3':
        autonomous();
        blades = 1;
        autonom = true;
        break;
      case '4':
        bladesOn();
        blades = true;
        break;
      case '0':
        Stop();
        autonom = false;
        blades = false;
        break;
    }
  }
}

void bw() {
  digitalWrite(M1A, 0); //Give an output to the M1A pin
  analogWrite(M1B, 255); //Give an output to the M1B pin
  digitalWrite(M2A, 0);
  analogWrite(M2B, 255);
  Serial.println("Backwards");
}

void fw() {
  digitalWrite(M1A, 1);
  analogWrite(M1B, (255 - 255));
  digitalWrite(M2A, 1);
  analogWrite(M2B, (255 - 255));
  Serial.println("Forwards");
}

void Stop() {
  digitalWrite(M1A, 0);
  analogWrite(M1B, 0);
  digitalWrite(M2A, 0);
  analogWrite(M2B, 0);
  Serial.println("Stop");
}

void autonomous() {
  while (autonom == true) {
    if (currentMillis - previousMillis <= fwdTime) {
      //When time between last repeat of forwards/reverse and now is less than Time1, go forward
        digitalWrite(M1A, 1);
        analogWrite(M1B, (255 - 255));
        digitalWrite(M2A, 1);
        analogWrite(M2B, (255 - 255));
        Serial.println("auto fwd");
    }
    if (currentMillis - previousMillis <= revTime) {
      //When time between last repeat of forwards/reverse and now is less than Time2, go reverse
        digitalWrite(M1A, 0);
        analogWrite(M1B, 255);
        digitalWrite(M2A, 0);
        analogWrite(M2B, 255);
        Serial.println("auto rev");
    }
    if (currentMillis - previousMillis == revTime) { //Set previoustime to currenttime
      previousMillis = currentMillis;
  Serial.println("Autonom");
    }
  }
}

void bladesOn() {
    blades = true;
    digitalWrite(M2A, 1);
    analogWrite(M2B, 0);
    Serial.println("Blades");
}
```

I know this is probably too long to read for some people, but any help would be very much appreciated. If you need more information, don't hesitate to ask.

PS. I am using "Arduino BT Joystick" as the Android app to control the robot, if that helps.

Thank you,

Craig.

Comment: This probably isn't all of your problem but I think you meant and should have the lines `autonom = true;` and `blades = 1;` before calling `autonomous();`. The first time `autonomous()` is called it won't perform the autonomy because `autonom` will be false.

Comment: How exactly do you expect your robot to not get **stuck** in an **infinite loop** within `autonomous()`, since there is **no exit chance** from the the `while(autonom == true) { ... }` loop it contains? You should set `autonom` to  `false` within that loop at some point or, even better, get rid of the loop entirely and adjust the rest of your code correspondingly.

Comment: Also, you forgot to update the value of `currentMillis`. More importantly, the condition `currentMillis - previousMillis == revTime` is an **hazard**: never use `==` on time variables, since it is very unlikely such condition will ever hold. Instead, use `<=` and `>=` appropriately. You should also try to separate the concept of *moving direction* from that of *length of movement*, having two variables `revTime` and `fwdTime` is an unnecessary complication.

Comment: I put currrentMillis = millis(); into the loop() { } and nothing happens. Does the loop(){ } get "turned off" while the while loop is running?

Comment: you should understand that calling a function is not spawning a thread: the function executes sequentially and up until when the function isn't over, your execution won't return to the caller. Updating that variable by itself isn't sufficient to fix your issue, since as i said you have more than one problem in your design.

Comment: So then how would I go about allowing the Bluetooth signal to stop the function? Or is it necessary to have a times exit? Because I want the user to be able to stop the function whenever they wish

Comment: @CraigStratford you simply have to decouple the code in which you *take a decision to do something* from the code in which you actually *do something*. I provided an answer that should clarify the *necessary design*.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic for the `autonomous()` function is wrong. The arduino will get stuck on the while loop on the second call of the function, as noted by DigitalNinja, as the autonom variable is only updated outside this loop.

Even if it wasn't the case, the `currentMillis` variable is not being updated anywhere in the code, so the test `currentMillis - previousMillis <= fwdTime` will always be true.

(Ps: sorry to answer like this, I don't have enough reputation to comment.)

Answer (score 0):

**Problems:**

1. `autonom()` contains a loop `while(autonom == true) { ... }` which does never terminate because `autonom` is never set to `false` within the loop, so the control never returns to caller `void loop() { ... }` and you never listen to **bluetooth** commands again.
2. You do not update `currentMillis` anywhere, thus your *robot* would end being stuck trying to go *forward*/*backward* forever.
3. It is inappropriate to write `currentMillis - previousMillis == revTime`, because generally speaking `currentMillis` might become *larger than* `previousMillis + revTime` without ever being *equal*. You should write `currentMillis - previousMillis >= revTime` instead.

---

Although not really complicated, your code is quite long and I don't have much time to spend over an answer, so I'll try to set you in the right direction by giving you the *mock-up* of a proper design in *pseudo-code*. I am confident that you'll be able to use it to your needs.

Please note that in this example `'1'` sets the autonomous movement forward and `'2'` sets the autonomous movement backward, and `'3'` is no longer used. This is because I think your communication protocol should be enriched so to allow for *command parameters*, *e.g.: the duration of movement*. Note that you can easily reproduce your previous behaviour for `'1'` and `'2'` by setting `time = 0`.

```
enum {
    STAY_STILL,
    MOVE_FORWARD,
    MOVE_BACKWARD,
}

#define FORWARD_TIME  20000
#define BACKWARD_TIME (FORWARD_TIME / 2)

byte state = STAY_STILL;
unsigned long startMillis;

void loop() {

    currentMillis = millis();

    if (BT.available()) {

        char input = BT.read();

        switch (input) {
        case '1':
           state = MOVE_FORWARD;
           time  = FORWARD_TIME;
           startMillis = currentMillis;
           break;
        case '2':
           state = MOVE_BACKWARD;
           time = BACKWARD_TIME;
           startMillis = currentMillis;
           break;
        // case '3' is pointless: instead of duplicating functionality
        // you should modify your communication protocol so to allow
        // setting both a direction and the amount of time you want
        // the robot to move in such direction. A value of 0 could
        // stand for 'forever', all other values could be interpreted
        // as seconds.
        case '4':
           start_blades();
           break;
        case '5':
           stop_blades();
           break;
        case '0':
           state = STAY_STILL;
           break;
        }
    }

    if (state == MOVE_FORWARD || state == MOVE_BACKWARD) {
        move_robot();
    } else if (state == STAY_STILL) {
        stop_blades();
        stop_robot();
    }

    delay(10);
}

void start_blades() {
  digitalWrite(M2A, 1);
  analogWrite(M2B, 0);
  Serial.println("start blades");
}

void stop_blades() {
  digitalWrite(M2A, 0);
  analogWrite(M2B, 0);
  Serial.println("stop blades");
}

void stop_robot() {
  digitalWrite(M1A, 0);
  analogWrite(M1B, 0);
  Serial.println("stop wheels");
}

void move_robot() {
    // time == 0 : move forever in one direction
    // else      : move up until deadline
    if (time == 0 || currentMillis - startMillis <= time) {
        if (state == MOVE_FORWARD) {
            fw();
        } else if (state == MOVE_BACKWARD) { 
            bw();
        }
    } else {
        // this will turn off both blades and
        // wheels at the next iteration of the loop()
        state = STAY_STILL;
    }
}

...
// your fw() and bw() functions
...
```

---

To conclude, a minor suggestion. In your place, I would change functions like `fw(), bw(), start_blades(), stop_blades(), stop_robot()` to perform an action only when it is necessary, instead of setting the values and printing stuff mindlessly. In addition to reducing the overhead of long functions, it also avoids printing tons of messages through *serial*, making *debugging* easier. This can be achieved by enriching the *robot's state* with more information, but it falls beyond the scope of the question and this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the end, I had a variable that was turning itself on and off apparently on its own. So when the due date came in for the project I took out the Auto function completely. Thanks for all your help guys, I mightn't have gotten it, but I learned a bit.

Comment: Could you, perhaps, indicate which exact part of the code wasn't working? As in, what variable was it?

Comment: it was the autonom variable. It had been set to false globally but still somehow, magically managed to set itself to true